# Centos Setup Command

Tags: centos5

What is the centos setup command used in the initial installation?  I have a vmware image and i used 'linux text' to install it; now i would like to go back and use the gui version to add some packages.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-graphical-rpm.html

Depending on which window manager you are using, you can either to to

Applications --> Add/Remove Software

Or from a shell type "system-config-packages".

If you get "command not found", then you would first have to run

yum install system-config-packages

Comment: +1 For providing more than just the link even though the link is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

After your system has been installed,  you generally install new packages by logging in and using the "yum" command.  This is covered in the CentOS documentation:

- http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/index.html

If you've installed a desktop environment on your system, you can use the graphical Package Management tool:

- http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-graphical-rpm.html

Comment: So there is no way to run anaconda where you can choose groups of packages, Development, Server, etc?  I know how to use yum but i want to use the groups because i am installing a proprietary rpm that has dependencies and it is failing.

Comment: You can use yum to install the third-party rpm and it will resolve any dependencies:  "yum install /path/to/file.rpm".  You can also use yum to install groups, see the yum man page and look at the group* command (grouplist, groupinstall, etc).

Comment: That should be yum localinstall /path/to/file.rpm, right?

Comment: Nope, just yum install.  Read the man page: "Note that  the  install  command  will do a local install, if given a filename."

Comment: You're right -- I learned it as localinstall (which works, too) and never tested otherwise.  Thanks for the tip!